# What is this character?

Tags: character, html-escape-characters, character-entities

I've found this character " ⚙ " on a webmail of a malaysian host
but I can't find its charcater entity **`(like &amp; = &#38; = &)`** nowhere.
Can anybody help me??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a character, not about programming.

Comment: Sorry @JukkaK.Korpela but I didn't know where I had to ask this question, could you kindly tell me which is the right topic?

Comment: Looks like a question suitable for SuperUser. And perhaps better formulated more generally: how do I find the identity of a character? (A good answer would be long, but perhaps not too long.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the [Unicode Character 'GEAR' (U+2699)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2699/index.htm) (HTML entity `&#x2699;`).